# How to create Enterprise Document Center Web Template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-template, document-center

I want to create a custom web template based on enterprise Document Center in sharepoint 2013. How I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Have a look at Vesas brilliant guide to creating web templates.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#webtemplate)

The Base ID you should use for a Document Center is `BDR#0`

Like:

```
<WebTemplate
           Name="MyDocumentCenter"
           BaseTemplateName="BDR"
           BaseTemplateID="9"
           BaseConfigurationID="0"
           Title="My Document Center"
           Description="Custom document center web template"
           DisplayCategory="Custom stuff"/>
```